# How to display all images fields on custom page with post type

Tags: image, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to loop through the fields of ACF to display all the images of a post type and a specific category

I give a practical example:
I have an ACF image field (image_of_project) and I want to view all the images uploaded in a post type (projects) associated with XYZ category

Now I created this loop:

'

```
        $loop = new WP_Query( array( 
            'post_type' => 'projects',
            'posts_per_page' => 9,
            ) );
        
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        $images = get_field('image_of_project');
        if( $images ): ?>
                <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                
                        <div class="item">
                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>" target="_blank">
                            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image ); ?>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>     
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

'

The images are displayed but I do not understand why it duplicates me every single image and does not show me only the images of linked to a specific category.

Thanks to anyone who will help me on this mission!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested in the feature, here’s how it worked for me.

function.php

```
// Loop Gallery Cat1

function my_custom_gallery_cat1() {
    query_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'gd_project',
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array (
                'taxonomy' => 'gd_projectcategory',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'example-terms',
            )
        ),
    ));
    ?> <div class="masonry">
    <?php
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        $image_field = get_field('image');
        $image_url = $image_field['url'];
        $image_alt = $image_field['alt']; ?>
        <div class="grid-item">
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>" target="_blank">
        <img src="<?php echo esc_url($image_url); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($image_alt); ?>" />
        <h4><?php the_field( 'title' ); ?></h4>
        </a>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div> <?php
}
add_shortcode('example-terms', 'my_custom_gallery_cat1');
```

single-example.php

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
  <?php echo do_shortcode('[categoria]');?>
 </div>    
</div>
```